# Determine whether $(\Bbb R,+,0)$ is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

I have to determine whether $(\Bbb R,+,0)$ is finitely generated. I am thinking of considering the following: if the group is finite Abelian then it is finitely generated. Would it suffice to show that it is abelian but it is not finite?

Comment: A finite group is always finitely generated. The generating set could be the whole group.

Comment: you have "if the group is finite abelian, then it is finitely generated". If you manage to show that R is not "finite abelian", then the conditional above is useless to you (false implies anything). This is not a group theory question, this is a logic question.

Comment: Hint:  this is really more an issue of set theory than one of group theory.

Comment: Even $(\Bbb Q,+)$ is not finitely generated, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592771/mathbbq-is-not-finitely-generated/2814261). The set of 
real numbers is uncountable, and any finitely generated group must be countable.

Comment: Can you say what is $(R,+,o)$ ? A ring ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two questions:

- If $A$ and $B$ implies $C$, and if $A$ but not $B$, then not $C$?

Obviously, no.

- Is the additive group of the reals finitely-generated?

No. Let $S$ be a finite subset in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\phi : \mathbb{Z}^S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the map sending $(n_s)_{s \in S}$ to $\sum_{s \in S} n_s s$, then $\phi$ is a group morphism. Since $\mathbb{Z}^S$ is countable, and $\mathbb{R}$ is not, it cannot be surjective.